Wrapping Shape and Image objects in a Drawing object in reportlab
I have a reporting programing framework using the reportlab.platypus module that can call several different kinds of chart generators that produce either a single reportlab.platypus.Image object or a single reportlab.graphics.shapes.Drawing object i.e.
def chart1():
   return Image(...)

def chart2():
   return Drawing()

We have some special requirements on legend handling and to date, we have been able to do this by "manually" creating little shapes.Rect and Label() and working up the x,y positioning and color, something like this (boiled down):
    d = Drawing(700, 220)
    bc = VerticalBarChart()

    #  Manually build legends:
    for item in labels:
            r = shapes.Rect(4,4,8,8)
            lab = Label()
            b = abbrevSect("chart",b)
            lab.setText(b)
            d.add(r)
            d.add(lab)
    d.add(bc)
    return d

Until now, we had no special requirements for graphics created by Image() but this has changed.  I tried the obvious:
    d = Drawing(700, 220)

    img_buffer = BytesIO()
    fig.write_image(img_buffer, format='jpg')
    img_buffer.seek(0)  # be kind; rewind!                                     

    image = Image(img_buffer, width=W*inch, height=H*inch)

    #  Manually build legends:
    for item in labels:
            r = shapes.Rect(4,4,8,8)
            lab = Label()
            b = abbrevSect("chart",b)
            lab.setText(b)
            d.add(r)
            d.add(lab)
    d.add(image)
    return d

but that fails with
    drawing.add(image)
  File "python3.9/site-packages/reportlab/graphics/shapes.py", line 346, in add
    assert isValidChild(node), "Can only add Shape or UserNode objects to a Group"

I have been banging away at this for a while and cannot seem to get an Image into a Drawing or otherwise combining 2 Image.  What might be a good way mix Image with Drawing such that a single composite object is returned?  I do not wish to add pillow to the mix.
